# Why do we use Remainder in the Countdown App?

Tags: javascript

I watched a JavaScript tutorial of building Countdown app. For JS, we wrote this code below. But I don't understand why do we need to take remainders %  and then divide to a bigger unit? Can someone explain? I didn't understand this part especially...

```
  //Calculate 
  const textDay = Math.floor(gap / day);
  const textHour = Math.floor((gap % day) / hour);
  const textMinute = Math.floor((gap % hour) / minute);
  const textSecond = Math.floor((gap % minute) / second);
```

```
//Basically we are getting the difference between the FUTURE and NOW . and ➖ substract the difference

const countdown = () => {
  const countDate = new Date("May 17, 2021 00:00:00").getTime();
  const now = new Date().getTime();
  const gap = countDate - now;

  //How does the time work❓
  const second = 1000;
  const minute = second * 60; //60000
  const hour = minute * 60; //3600000
  const day = hour * 24;

  //Calculate 
  const textDay = Math.floor(gap / day);
  const textHour = Math.floor((gap % day) / hour);
  const textMinute = Math.floor((gap % hour) / minute);
  const textSecond = Math.floor((gap % minute) / second);

  //Update our actual HTML
  document.querySelector(".day").innerText = textDay;
  document.querySelector(".hour").innerText = textHour;
  document.querySelector(".minute").innerText = textMinute;
  document.querySelector(".second").innerText = textSecond;
};

setInterval(countdown, 1000);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The gap is in milliseconds. If you get the remainder of `gap % day` and `day` being the milliseconds per day then you will get everything that doesn't fit into whole days => all smaller units (hours, minutes, seconds and milliseconds).

e.g.:

```js
const countdown = () => {
  // Lets just say gap is 5.5 days = 5.5 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 milliseconds
  const gaps = 475200000;

  // These are the equivalents of the time units in milliseconds
  const second = 1000;        // =     1000 ms
  const minute = second * 60; // =    60000 ms
  const hour = minute * 60;   // =  3600000 ms
  const day = hour * 24;      // = 86400000 ms

  //Calculate 
  const textDay = Math.floor(gap / day); // This will return 5 days
  
  let remainder = gap % day; // This will be 5.5 % 1 = 0.5 days or 43200000 ms
  const textHour = Math.floor(remainder / hour); // This will return 12 hours
  
  // gap = 5.5 days = 132 hours
  remainder = gap % hour; // This will be 132 % 1 = 0
  const textMinute = Math.floor(remainder / minute); // This will return 0

  // gap = 5.5 days = 7920 minutes
  remainder = gap % minutes; // This will be 7920 % 1 = 0
  const textSecond = Math.floor(remainder  / second); // This will return 0

  //Update our actual HTML
  document.querySelector(".day").innerText = textDay;
  document.querySelector(".hour").innerText = textHour;
  document.querySelector(".minute").innerText = textMinute;
  document.querySelector(".second").innerText = textSecond;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

How do remainders work? In simple words: The "left-over" is what remains. It's like a divison but you are only interested in the "left-over" part.

see the following 2 examples with explanation:

```
100 / 10 = 10 # what is the "left-over"? it is 0
                because 10*10 = 100 and 100 - 100 = 0
                in other words 100 % 10 = 0
```

---

```
103 / 10 = 10 # what is the "left-over"? it is 3
                because 10*10 = 100 and 103 - 100 = 3
                in other words 103 % 10 = 3
```

```js
console.log('100 % 10 = ', 100 % 10)
console.log('103 % 10 = ', 103 % 10)
```

Now, say you have `75 minutes`. You know this is `1h and 15min`. How can you get `15` out of `75`? The simple trick `75 % 60 = 15`